# Getting syntax error near unexpected token '../lib/cli.js'` error when launching app using pm2 start

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, npm, pm2

I am getting an issue when doing `pm2 start` with an `ecosystem.config.js`

```
/root/.nvm/versions/node/v18.16.0/bin/npm: line 2: require('../lib/cli.js')(process)'
/root/.nvm/versions/node/v18.16.0/bin/npm: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token '../lib/cli.js''
```

I made a complete reinstallation of node on my machine but still getting tis issue.

nvm -v 0.39.3
node -v 18.16.0
npm -v 9.5.1
pm2 -v 5.3.0

```js
module.exports = {
  apps: [
    {
      name: "strapi_portfolio",
      cwd: "./server",
      script: "npm",
      args: "run start-prod",
      autorestart: true,
    },
    {
      name: "nextjs_portfolio",
      cwd: "./client",
      script: "npm",
      args: "run start-prod",
      autorestart: true,
      wait_ready: true,
      listen_timeout: 60000,
    },
  ],
};
```

my `start-prod` script :

```
"start-prod" : "npm install && npm run build && npm run start"
```

What I'm not getting is that my processes work when launched individually and manually...

Looks like they are working but encounter an unknown issue at some point
[image]

### PM2 report

```
--- PM2 report ----------------------------------------------------------------
Date                 : Wed Jun 14 2023 00:52:29 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)
===============================================================================
--- Daemon -------------------------------------------------
pm2d version         : 5.3.0
node version         : 18.16.0
node path            : /root/.local/share/pnpm/pm2
argv                 : /root/.nvm/versions/node/v18.16.0/bin/node,/root/.local/share/pnpm/global/5/.pnpm/pm2@5.3.0/node_modules/pm2/lib/Daemon.js
argv0                : node
user                 : root
uid                  : 0
gid                  : 0
uptime               : 14min
===============================================================================
--- CLI ----------------------------------------------------
local pm2            : 5.3.0
node version         : 18.16.0
node path            : /root/.local/share/pnpm/pm2
argv                 : /root/.nvm/versions/node/v18.16.0/bin/node,/root/.local/share/pnpm/global/5/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2,report
argv0                : node
user                 : root
uid                  : 0
gid                  : 0
===============================================================================
--- System info --------------------------------------------
arch                 : x64
platform             : linux
type                 : Linux
cpus                 : AMD EPYC 7282 16-Core Processor
cpus nb              : 4
freemem              : 7807197184
totalmem             : 8346025984
home                 : /root
===============================================================================
--- PM2 list -----------------------------------------------
┌────┬─────────────────────┬─────────────┬─────────┬─────────┬──────────┬────────┬──────┬───────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┐
│ id │ name                │ namespace   │ version │ mode    │ pid      │ uptime │ ↺    │ status    │ cpu      │ mem      │ user     │ watching │
├────┼─────────────────────┼─────────────┼─────────┼─────────┼──────────┼────────┼──────┼───────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┤
│ 1  │ nextjs_portfolio    │ default     │ 0.39.3  │ fork    │ 0        │ 0      │ 30   │ errored   │ 0%       │ 0b       │ root     │ disabled │
│ 0  │ strapi_portfolio    │ default     │ 0.39.3  │ fork    │ 0        │ 0      │ 30   │ errored   │ 0%       │ 0b       │ root     │ disabled │
└────┴─────────────────────┴─────────────┴─────────┴─────────┴──────────┴────────┴──────┴───────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┘
===============================================================================
--- Daemon logs --------------------------------------------
/root/.pm2/pm2.log last 20 lines:
PM2        | 2023-06-14T00:42:03: PM2 log: Script /root/.nvm/versions/node/v18.16.0/bin/npm had too many unstable restarts (16). Stopped. "errored"
PM2        | 2023-06-14T00:42:03: PM2 log: App [nextjs_portfolio:1] starting in -fork mode-
PM2        | 2023-06-14T00:42:03: PM2 log: App [nextjs_portfolio:1] exited with code [2] via signal [SIGINT]
PM2        | 2023-06-14T00:42:03: PM2 log: Script /root/.nvm/versions/node/v18.16.0/bin/npm had too many unstable restarts (16). Stopped. "errored"
PM2        | 2023-06-14T00:43:03: PM2 log: App [nextjs_portfolio:1] online
PM2        | 2023-06-14T00:43:03: PM2 log: App [nextjs_portfolio:1] online
PM2        | 2023-06-14T00:43:03: PM2 log: App [nextjs_portfolio:1] online
PM2        | 2023-06-14T00:43:03: PM2 log: App [nextjs_portfolio:1] online
PM2        | 2023-06-14T00:43:03: PM2 log: App [nextjs_portfolio:1] online
PM2        | 2023-06-14T00:43:03: PM2 log: App [nextjs_portfolio:1] online
PM2        | 2023-06-14T00:43:03: PM2 log: App [nextjs_portfolio:1] online
PM2        | 2023-06-14T00:43:03: PM2 log: App [nextjs_portfolio:1] online
PM2        | 2023-06-14T00:43:03: PM2 log: App [nextjs_portfolio:1] online
PM2        | 2023-06-14T00:43:03: PM2 log: App [nextjs_portfolio:1] online
PM2        | 2023-06-14T00:43:03: PM2 log: App [nextjs_portfolio:1] online
PM2        | 2023-06-14T00:43:03: PM2 log: App [nextjs_portfolio:1] online
PM2        | 2023-06-14T00:43:03: PM2 log: App [nextjs_portfolio:1] online
PM2        | 2023-06-14T00:43:03: PM2 log: App [nextjs_portfolio:1] online
PM2        | 2023-06-14T00:43:03: PM2 log: App [nextjs_portfolio:1] online
PM2        | 2023-06-14T00:43:03: PM2 log: App [nextjs_portfolio:1] online
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I just used the wrong node version...

I coded my projects using node `v16.16.0` but tried to start them using node `v18.16.0`

I downloaded `v16.16.0` using nvm and then added this line in my `ecosystem.config.js`

```js
interpreter: "node@16.16.0"
```

So it looks like so :

```js
module.exports = {
  apps: [
    {
      name: "strapi_portfolio",
      interpreter: "node@16.16.0", // HERE
      cwd: "./server",
      script: "npm",
      args: "run start-prod",
      autorestart: true,
    },
    {
      name: "nextjs_portfolio",
      interpreter: "node@16.16.0", // HERE
      cwd: "./client",
      script: "npm",
      args: "run start-prod",
      autorestart: true,
      wait_ready: true,
      listen_timeout: 60000,
    },
  ],
};
```